# After updating a df from filtred df old values reappear

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

i have a df where i have a requirement to filter it into new df and work on it and after working i wanted to update it to the original df like.

| Street | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4210 Nw Lake Dr | Lees Summit | Mo | 64064 |
| 9810 Scripps Lake Dr. Suite A San Diego | Ca - 92131 |  |  |
| 1124 Ethel St | Glendale | Ca | 91207 |
| 4000 E Bristol St Ste 3 Elkhart | In-46514 |  |  |

my intened output is

| Street | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4210 Nw Lake Dr | Lees Summit | Mo | 64064 |
| 9810 Scripps Lake Dr. Suite A San Diego |  | Ca | 92131 |
| 1124 Ethel St | Glendale | Ca | 91207 |
| 4000 E Bristol St Ste 3 Elkhart |  | In | 46514 |

So firstly i filtered the original dataframe into a new df and worked on it.

with following code

```
Filter3_df= Final[Final['State'].isnull()]
Filter3_df['temp'] = Filter3_df['City'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)')
mask2= Filter3_df['temp'].notnull()
Filter3_df.loc[mask2, 'Zip']    = Filter3_df.loc[mask2, 'City'].str[-5:]
Filter3_df.loc[mask2, 'State']  = Filter3_df.loc[mask2, 'temp']
del Filter3_df['temp']
Filter3_df['City']= float('NaN')
```

after this the table for Filter3_df looks like this

| Street | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9810 Scripps Lake Dr. Suite A San Diego |  | Ca | 92131 |
| 4000 E Bristol St Ste 3 Elkhart |  | In | 46514 |

but when i update this filtered_df back to the original df using

```
Final.update(Filter3_df)
```

I am not getting the intended output instead I am getting the output as

| Street | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4210 Nw Lake Dr | Lees Summit | Mo | 64064 |
| 9810 Scripps Lake Dr. Suite A San Diego | Ca - 92131 | Ca | 92131 |
| 1124 Ethel St | Glendale | Ca | 91207 |
| 4000 E Bristol St Ste 3 Elkhart | In-46514 | In | 46514 |

kindly let me know where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html#pandas-dataframe-update):

```
Modify in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame.
```

Replace `Filter3_df['City']= float('NaN')`, which is NA for floats, with the value you really want:

```
Filter3_df['City'] = ""
```